# ClassNotFoundException when running JUnit test in Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm currently trying to set up automated testing for a Maven project, but I've run into a problem. When running my tests using `mvn test`, I get the following result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: no.digipat.patornat.servlets.ServletTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.398 s <<< FAILURE! - in no.digipat.patornat.servlets.ServletTests
no.digipat.patornat.servlets.ServletTests  Time elapsed: 0.368 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/OperationExecutor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.OperationExecutor
```

I get the same error when running the tests in Eclipse.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>no.digipat.patornat</groupId>
  <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Pat or Nat Backend</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>cytomine-uliege-Cytomine-java-client</id>
      <url>https://packagecloud.io/cytomine-uliege/Cytomine-java-client/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lordofthejars</groupId>
      <artifactId>nosqlunit-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
      <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0-RC2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
      <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
      <version>1.19.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>be.cytomine.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>cytomine-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>ServletTests.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The relevant Java files:

ServletTests.java:

```
package no.digipat.patornat.servlets;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.EnvironmentVariables;
import org.junit.rules.RuleChain;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

import static com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.mongodb.InMemoryMongoDb.InMemoryMongoRuleBuilder.newInMemoryMongoDbRule;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({MyTest.class})
public class ServletTests {

    private static final EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables();
    @ClassRule
    public static final TestRule chain = RuleChain
        .outerRule(newInMemoryMongoDbRule().build())
        .around(environmentVariables);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        environmentVariables.set("MY_VARIABLE", "some value");
    }

}
```

MyTest.java:

```
package no.digipat.patornat.servlets;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? I tried running `mvn clean` (which previously helped me fix a similar issue), but to no avail.

Comment: you need it for test scope: 

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: @Cayman That would just reduce the scope, since dependencies with "compile" scope are meant to be available when running tests. In addition to that, it's not really an option because I need the Mongo driver for more than just testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that the latest versions of Fongo and mongo-java-driver are incompatible. When I change the dependencies of Fongo and/or the Mongo Java driver to older versions (I specifically tried versions 2.1.0 and 3.6.3, respectively), the error disappears. However, since this solution seems rather fragile and inflexible, the best bet is probably to switch to an alternative to Fongo. According to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo/issues/316#issuecomment-436440615), [mongo-java-server](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/mongo-java-server) could be a good option. A perhaps more robust alternative, and the one I'll probably end up using, is to use a "real" test database. [This article](https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/) has information about a couple of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `maven-compiler-plugin` in your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
  <!-- put here the path of your test source directory -->
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ...
```